# Communicating from server to client

Tags: ios, sql-server, mobile, server, client-server

I'm developing an iOS application similar to uber or easyTaxi. My scenario has two users; driver and customer. When a customer pushes an order, it goes to all drivers. My problem is I have to keep pulling orders from the server on driver sides every few seconds for new orders or any updates on a particular order, which I think is not a correct approach as it will eventually overload the server. Is there a way where the server can update drivers as soon as an order is pushed to the server?

Or pulling is the only way here.

I'm kinda lost here, so even a if you can put me into the right direction, would be great.

Comment: You need to learn about RFC protocols. Or to put it in easier way check out https://www.pubnub.com, or XMPP server.

Comment: Thank fro your direction.let me check that out

Comment: Please contact [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support) if you need further insights into how to use PubNub. Also see use case: [Connected Cars: Build Transportation Management and Dispatch Apps](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-01-29-connected-cars-build-transportation-management-and-dispatch-apps/).